# Lubuntu 16.04.3 - How to remove old kernels safely

Tags: kernel

I have many old kernels and I'd like to know **which is the safest way to remove 
them**.

Thank you

Comment: Always check what new kernel working fine. Once I had a problem with new kernel drivers, and were forced to boot old kernel for few months, until they fixed it.

Comment: @karel,I read this thread before,I made the question to understand which is the best solution.@N0rbert,I didn't read your answer before,now I read that you use purge-old-kernels.Therefore I have the same doubt.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt autoremove`

The `man` (manual) page states autoremove

```
       autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
       installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
       longer needed.
```

which includes old kernels.

Comment: ps: looking online I note some add a `--purge` to the command, but I've never needed it.